# playing 2 or more .wav files one after another in java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wav

basically i want to play captcha digits. i have 1.wav, 2.wav etc.
i will send captcha digits to a function will seperate digits in the function and for each digit want to play corresponding .wav file. 
Just for simple example, if i want to play 1.way, 2.way and 3.way, i am using :

```
function PlayCaptcha() 
    {

        document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
        document.getElementById('audiotag2').play();
       document.getElementById('audiotag3').play();          
    }
```

and

`<audio id="audiotag1" src="sounds/1.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="audiotag2" src="sounds/2.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="audiotag3" src="sounds/3.wav" preload="auto"></audio>`

PROBLEM is that it plays all file at very high speed. and only 3.wav playing can be listened.
i wish to have some gap after 1.wav is played then 2.wav is played then again some time gap and then 3.wav should be played.

Any solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `onended` event of Audio, *Alert that the audio has ended*

Try this:

```js
function PlayCaptcha() {
  var audiotag1 = document.getElementById('audiotag1');
  var audiotag2 = document.getElementById('audiotag2');
  var audiotag3 = document.getElementById('audiotag3');
  audiotag1.play();
  audiotag1.onended = function() {
    audiotag2.play();
  };
  audiotag2.onended = function() {
    audiotag3.play();
  };
  audiotag3.onended = function() {
    alert('Ended!');
  };
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked in Google Chrome.  BUT its not working in IE. Seems to be browser Issue. any idea ?